# MobFox iOS integration "Cannot find protocol declaration"

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, protocols, mobfox

I have been trying to integrate MobFox in one of my iOS apps and I'm stuck with a problem.

I have added the framework to the project, and all the other necessary files as well but when I try to add `MobFoxVideoInterstitialViewControllerDelegate` under `@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate, MobFoxVideoInterstitialViewControllerDelegate>{ /*...*/ }` in my `MainViewController.h` file, it says `Cannot find protocol declaration for MobFoxVideoInterstitialViewControllerDelegate`. All the files are there. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's old, but I want to answer it. The problem was that someone tried to integrate MobFox already without video and didn't remove the files. So the library used those files instead of new ones. Removing old files has resolved my problem